# Is there a better one ? Encryption -> AES. PRNG -> Blum Blum Shub?

Tags: encryption, arm, random, aes, n900

Is there a better algorithm than AES-256 ?
AES is an industry standard symmetric algorithm. But theoretically its told to have flaws. Is there any symmetric algorithm (needn't be a standard), that's highly praised for its security? I'm collecting information on algorithms in-order to make a wallet to store some text for a specific device.

I read that Blum Blum Shub is a notable pseudo random generator algorithm, mainly used in cryptography rather than simulation. Here my focus is cryptography. So is it the best PRNG out there or is there any better one? I wanted to implement it for an ARM A8 Core CPU architecture in ARM assembly just from learning the asm, the architecture, and those algorithms in depth.

Does (or is it possible) using a gpu for encryption/decryption any better? My device in interest is N900 tablet (to learn more about the hardware and software).

Comment: What theoretical flaws in AES are you referring to? Provide a reference please. Blum Blum and Shub (BBS) has some provable security properties; some people get excited about these, I think they are mostly worthless. You will find that BBS is too slow for your needs.

Comment: GregS: You're mind reading capabilities are amazing.  Could you (or jase21) elaborate on what the PRNG will be used for in this application?  Also, check out NIST SP 800-90 for standardized PRNGs - they can be hash or cipher based so you could use the same cipher algorithm as the basis for your PRNG security.

Comment: @TomMD: It is not my application. And whose mind am I reading? NIST SP 800-90 is a good reference.

Comment: @GregS: I was being snide (perhaps overly so).  You claimed BBS is too slow for his needs, but I can't tell exactly what his needs are wrt performance so I don't know what constitutes "too slow".

Comment: @TomMD: Oh, yeah, I guess I am making some assumptions.

Comment: I wanted to build a password store (or just a wallet) that can encrypt documents (journals). About AES: http://www.betanews.com/article/Is-AES-encryption-crackable/1257437160

Answer (score 1):

It is true that AES is not the best and newest security algorithm but it may be the one with the ARM8 because it is part of the supply contract and may not be replaceable - it could be for compliance with FIPS standards in the US or the method the country or province of intended use has specified. You could do simple manipulate or substitute of text or numeric data yourself before sending it to AES and remember to write the code for the reverse process so you can reconstruct the data correctly and write, display or print it out.